# How to create a JFrame within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How can we create a main JFrame with background image and a JFrame inside the main JFrame with Java Swing?

Comment: I have a [drinking problem](http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f380/allelse/anythingelse/airplane1213112.jpg)

Comment: I think you mean unhelpful :P

Comment: Repeat question for image background
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466240/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [internal frames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

For the background image bit, sublass JPanel, override its paintComponent() method, and blit your image there. Then set an instance of that panel as your JFrame's content pane.

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage bgImg;

    public BackgroundPanel() {
        try {
            bgImg = ImageIO.read(BackgroundPanel.class.getResourceAsStream(
                    "mybackgroundimage.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not load background image!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (bgImg != null) {
            g.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyJFrame() {
        setContentPane(new BackgroundPanel());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to know what you are meaning with

> a JFrame inside the main JFrame

Have a read about what a [JFrame](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) really is. Maybe you want a [dialog window](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) in your application, or maybe an [internal window](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Or maybe just another [panel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

To get an background image in a JFrame, I recommend that you simply add a [JPanel with a backround image](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm) to the JFrame:s contentpane.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you won't need to nest a JFrame inside another JFrame and I don't think it is good design to do so too. What you can do is nest JPanels instead.

You will mainly need to know about these two classes:

- JPanel ->
  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html
- Graphics ->
  http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html