# How to add a background image for JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-image

I have a ball class which moves in a circle like a particle I want to place a background image behind the ball panel.

Comment: you may want to take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466240/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java)

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/swing_ex/JPanelCustomBkground.java it is a broader solution which uses Paint rather than Image... The main method demonstrates how to get a Paint from an Image

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: Another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944795/trouble-figuring-out-how-to-set-background-image/13945145#13945145)

Answer (score 0):

You can place JLabel on bottom layer with image set as Icon. Make it as large as frame and voila.