# JFrame Back Ground Image that other buttons don't appear on frame when background image is set?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, background-image

I want to add a background image to my frame.But when i add an image to my frame it was added successfully but other things like j label and buttons added on frame afterwords don't appear on frame. i have kept image on Desktop. below is my code

```
package UI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class EditTeamInterface extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EditTeamInterface frame = new EditTeamInterface();
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                    //frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
                    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Abdullah/Desktop/cricketBackGround1.jpg")))));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public EditTeamInterface() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 624, 356);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("EDIT OPTIONS");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("SketchFlow Print", Font.BOLD, 18));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 5;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 5;
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);
    }

}
```

Comment: Image size is set to size of my laptop screen that is 1337 horizontal by 670 vertical pixels

Answer (score 1):

In the `EditTeamInterface`'s constructor, you set the content pane for the frame using `setContentPane(contentPane);`, but in the `static void main`, you replace it with

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Abdullah/Desktop/cricketBackGround1.jpg")))));
```

This discards everything you did before for this new content...

Instead of `EditTeamInterface` extending from `JFrame`, change it so that it extends from `JPanel`

Create a new instance of a `JFrame`, set the content pane to your label and then add `EditTeamInterface` to the frame.

Because `JLabel` has no layout manager by default, you should call `setLayout(new BorderLayout())` on the frame after you set it's content pane to the label

While, using a `JLabel`, this way will work, `JLabel` will NOT calculate it's preferred size based on the needs of it's contents, but rather based on the properties of the `icon` and `text`.  This doesn't really make it suitable for this task.

A better solution is to use a custom `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` to render the image you want.  If you're clever, you will make it so that this class is re-usable.

Something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944795/trouble-figuring-out-how-to-set-background-image/13945145#13945145)