# Java - Color or Image cannot be set as Background

Tags: java, swing, colors

Basically I've created two classes; Main and JFrameOptions.
However, it seems that I cannot draw a background whether I use JLabels, setContentPane or setBackground all of them doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Main:

```
package game;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrameOptions.Options();
TSDTDir.Directory();
}
}
```

JFrameOptions:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JFrameOptions{

 static String setTitle = ("Game");;

 public static int width = 920;
 public static int height = 517;

public static void Options() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame(setTitle);
    window.setSize(width, height);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.toFront();
    window.setBackground(Color.black);
}
}
```

Edit:

I got the fundamental thing to work through your answers:  `window.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.PINK );`

But how can I load an image that has to function to have a login field for example?

Edit 2:
It is not working. The background doesn't draw.

```
public static void Options() {

        //Displays the title 
        JFrame window = new JFrame(setTitle);
        window.setSize(width, (int) height);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setIconImage(favIcon);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.toFront();

        //window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);


        BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("Background.png"));
        window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And of course the Background.png file is in the directory of the game folder: http://prntscr.com/9kxc4i

Image of image file location:
[image]

Console image:
[image]

Running GUI image:
[image]

Comment: In the future, please search on your problem before posting because 9 times out of 10, it's been asked and answered before.

Comment: Links: [JFrame set background color not working](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jframe+set+background+color+not+working+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F), and [JFrame set background image](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jframe+set+background+image+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: `"But how can I load an image that has to function to have a login field for example?"` -- again look it up -- see links above. As for "login field" you'll have to describe what you mean as that doesn't make sense, but perhaps you mean to show a modal JDialog as a login window, and if so, look that up. There is nothing new under the sun.

Comment: Alright let me explain more in depth: I want to draw an image: http://i.imgur.com/Nr9PVYl.png - Which in the bottom of course loads the content.. after that I want to have another image: http://i.imgur.com/93A8N98.png - Which has to be drawn and have these login input fields to function ( I know there is something about positioning etc.)
Also I have looked on every single article and seems to I cannot figure it out as it didn't draw the image..
- I am new into Java btw..

Comment: Again, the links will explain how to draw images. You will want to check them and try. If still stuck, then come back **with your new attempt** code. Else we're being forced to give the same answers that have already been given before.

Comment: Fully understandable I will try again and come back if it isn't working!

Comment: Updated the above post

Comment: Your new problem is likely due to another common problem -- not being able to read in an image file, which is usually due to looking in the wrong place. Have you checked the path to the user's working directory? This can be obtained by printing `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`. Then check to see where your image path is in relation to this path, and then correct your path. Also when debugging, try to avoid having such long compressed lines of code. Read the image on one line, create the Icon on another, check for nulls.

Comment: Just outprinted the code you gave me and it is the correct path; "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Game" and the background's path is located at : "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Game\Background.png"

That's why I do not get why it is not displayed. Also I do not quite get the last part with the "debugging" though I think I know what you mean with the long compressed lines of code.

Comment: I'll re-open your question given the efforts you're putting in, but your problem now vexes me. Are you getting an IIOException with this attempt? Show all exceptions, show by image (post a link to an image) the location of your image relative to your code please.

Comment: I really do understand it vexes me as well but I have learned that patience is key and I really appreciate that you are helping! Alright the fact is with this problem is that it recognizes the file however doesn't draw it. No exceptions occurs at the console. Location of image: http://prntscr.com/9kxc4i - Console output: http://prntscr.com/9kxsag - Screen of the frame: http://prntscr.com/9kxsgs - JFrameOptions class: http://pastebin.com/eBmYJTwU - Main class: http://pastebin.com/NKWCMy2D

Comment: I tested it if I remove the file at the location a  IIOException will occur: http://prntscr.com/9kxtl8

Comment: Images uploaded. In the future, please post links to the images, not to the web pages that hold the images.

Comment: Hovercraft or anyone else is the way I am calling a method on OK? Like the main args calls the options method from another class? Also do i've to do that every single time i want something to be runned?

Comment: Start by using `ImageIO.read` to load the image instead of `ImageIcon`, it will through an error if the image can't be loaded for some reason

Comment: I think the case is that it is not being drawn into the frame. No exception occur as said earlier. Also I do use ImageIO.read?

Comment: Sorry, reading on the phone, move `window.setVisible(true);` so it is the last call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, you are calling `setVisible` before the UI is established.  Swing is lazy when it comes to laying out changes to the UI, requiring you to decide when the UI should be updated, this is deliberate and done in order to maintain efficiency (imagine adding a dozen new components to the UI, you wouldn't want the UI to be revalidated and updated until you're done, otherwise you'd be wasting a lot of time)

The simple solution is, call `setVisible` last...

```
public static void Options() {

    //Displays the title 
    JFrame window = new JFrame(setTitle);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setIconImage(favIcon);

    //window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("Background.png"));
        window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.toFront();
}
```

Remember though, a `JLabel` has no layout manager by default and even when you apply one, it won't use it to calculate its `preferredSize`, relying only on the `icon` and `text` properties.

Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424095/jframe-back-ground-image-that-other-buttons-dont-appear-on-frame-when-backgroun/28424212#28424212) for more details and alternatives

Comment: Dang, that is a nice explanation. Though I came up with another solution which I actually do not get why it works?

I simply added after e.printStackTrace(); } Graphics g = window.getGraphics(); g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

And it draw the image to the frame?

Comment: Don't (ever) use `getGraphics`, it's simply a snapshot of what was last painted to the component and will be overriden the next time the component is repainted

Comment: Oh I see, so basically that means if I drag the frame to right then the dragged area would become white as it gets overriden?

Comment: Assuming you didn't also add the label, yes (resizing the frame with the label would invalidate the container, causing it to be re-laid out and repainted)

Comment: I understand now, though it is working properly now with your code. It happended before with the getGraphics. Definitely this has being a lot useful.