# how to set a background JFrame picture with eclipse

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with my code, I'm farelly new to java programming but the thing is that I want to set a bg picture but the code that I use disapears everything else that I've put in the JFrame..

```
panel.setSize(950, 600);
panel.setTitle("Nuevo Usuario Otto's");
panel.setResizable(false);
panel.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
try {
    panel.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\CELLES_PROYECTO\\darkTrees.jpg")))));
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
panel.setResizable(false);
panel.pack();
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: update your complete code in question.

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466240/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java

Answer (score 0):

JLabel does not support child components. Instead, use a JPanel for the content pane, and override its paintComponent method to draw the image.

```
try {
    final Image backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\CELLES_PROYECTO\\darkTrees.jpg"));
    setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
        @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The above example also sets the JPanel's layout to BorderLayout, to match the default content pane layout.