# How to draw PNG Image onto JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, drawing, jpanel

I'm trying to draw a image onto a JPanel by overriding the `paintComponent` method. However, I'm having no luck with it at all and I don't know why.

Here's the code I've got at the moment:

**DrawPanel**

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    private Image backgroundImg;

    public DrawPanel()
    {
        backgroundImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\Scrub\\src\\loginBackground.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

**LoginWindow Class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoginWindow extends Window{

    private DrawPanel panel;

    public LoginWindow(int width, int height)
    {
        super("", width, height);


        panel = new DrawPanel();
        this.add(panel);

        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow(500, 300);


    }
}
```

Comment: you want background image right? then maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203049/java-background-not-showing-up/22203780#22203780

Comment: then to stop repainting for JPanel

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of reasons this might not work

- The image might not be getting loaded. You should use `ImageIO.read` instead, as it will throw an `IOException` if something goes wrong
- The layout manager is using the preferred size of your panel, which is defaulted to 0x0, making the component effectively invisible
- You're not setting the window to be visible...

For example

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
    //...
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return backgroundImg == null ? new Dimesion(100, 100) : new Dimension(backgroundImg.getWidth(this), backgroundImg.gtHeight(this));
    }
```

And then in your Window class...

```
public LoginWindow(int width, int height)
{
    super("", width, height);


    panel = new DrawPanel();
    this.add(panel);

    // Swing components are visible by default
    //panel.setVisible(true);
    // windows aren't
    setVisible(true);
}
```

A simpler soliton would be to use a `JLabel`...

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(...));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
add(label);
setVisible(true);
```

Take a look at [How to use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. About what you've said for Window's being visible. The LoginWindow extends to another class called Window that I have created. In this super class, I have `setVisible(true)` so it doesn't needs to be called again. In fact, the window shows it's just not drawing the image, thats all.

Comment: Okay, lesson, try and avoid using class names that already exist if you can or identify them early on.  The rest should be valid...